# How to update Atlassian Confluence Wiki using JMeter and the REST API

Tags: jmeter, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I wanted a way to update a wiki status page and upload a file after a JMeter test was done running.  This is something that you could conditionally kick off depending on the results of your Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with these steps:

1. in a setup thread group, added a BeanShell Sampler to locate the most recent report file in my results folder.

   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; 
       import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter;
       import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
       import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;

   ```
   log.info("GET MOST RECENT RESULTS REPORT FOR THE APP TESTED");
   String dir_path = props.get("test_results_path");
   File theNewestFile = null;

    try {
      File dir = new File(dir_path);
      FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("Results_${testApp}*.*");
      File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
    if (files.length > 0) {
           /** The newest file comes first **/
           Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
           theNewestFile = files[0];
           String fileName = files[0].getName().toString();
           log.info("fileName:  "+fileName);
           print("fileName:  "+fileName);
           props.put("varResultsReportFile",fileName);
       }

       return theNewestFile;
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Failed in Beanshell", ex);
      throw ex;
   }
   ```
2. login with a wiki/confluence system account
3. GET `rest/api/content?title=${testApp}&spaceKey=${testSpaceKey}&expand=version,history`
4. Use a JSON Extractors to extract page Version number(`results..version.number`) and page id(`results..id`)
5. Use a BeanShell PostProcessor to add 1 to the page version number and store that value in a variable. You will need this when you PUT your update into the wiki
6. GET `rest/api/content?title=${testApp}&spaceKey=${testSpaceKey}&expand=body.storage`
7. Use JSON Extractor to extact page body value(`results..body.storage.value`)
8. Using a CSS/JQuery Extractor on the JMeter Variable you created in step 7, Extract all the table values. For example,CSS/JQuery Expression=td and Match No= 1 to extract first column value.
9. PUT `rest/api/content/${varPageId}` and in the JSON body, update the single table value that you need to update and restore the values you extracted that you dont need updated.
10. POST `rest/api/content/${varResultsPageId}/child/attachment`  For the Files upload tab, File Path=${__P(test_results_path)}${__P(varResultsReportFile)}, Parameter Name=file, MIME Type=text/csv
11. logout